# How do I use an index hint with a Mongo C# LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

I am getting an index warning from Mongo Labs similar to the below message when making a LINQ call using the MongoDB C# driver:

xyz_user_dev.MyCollection
{"ClientId": -1}
The existing {"ClientId": 1} index cannot be used for this query as it is sparse. Sparse indexes will not be used (unless hinted) when they would return incomplete results.

I found this link which explains a method to fix this, by using the mongo sparse index:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-668

I just can't figure out how to use the WithIndex() in a Mongo C# LINQ query. I can see the extension method in the nuget package, but I can't seem to be able to use it anywhere (compiler error).

Someone please help

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to create an index from C# in MongoDB database or are you trying to execute a query by using a previous created index?

Comment: Can you show the not working code ?

Comment: To fix the compilation issue you probably just need to add a `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: (2) The code works. It just does not use the sparse index because of the way mongo works.

Comment: (1) Trying to optimize the query

Comment: (3) The class where they added the support for this is no longer in the nuget package. But I was able to take the code from github put it in my own class and use the extension method. Now the problem is that I don't specify the index name when creating the index, and mongo labs does not show me the index names, so I have the method useable now, but unable to use the hint. Also, may not make sense to change 1000+ lines of code adding index hints everywhere.

Comment: You can retrieve the list of the indexes in MongoDB with this command: db.collection.getIndexes()

Comment: FYI.. Mongo Labs confirmed this is a bug on their end. Sparse indexes will be used for queries as long as you are searching the index for a non-null value - which is the case for me. They will fix the warning from their end.